# The relevance of the ' UIImageView Opaque' option in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Apples documentation states that the correct use of the Opaque option can result in performance optimisations. I am just a little unclear as to when to tick the option and when not to. All new `UIImageViews` in IB have the option ticked by default.

So, say I have two `UIImageViews`, both square and filled with two square pngs that I made in Photoshop. The first png is a background image for my app and has no transparent pixels. The second is a round ball/circle with no background and therefore has transparent pixels.

How would the `Opaque` option work with both scenarios?

Comment: [This Article](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/moving-pixels-onto-the-screen.html) may help you to figure it out yourself.

Comment: johnMa, I read that article, it was a good read. It didn't really anwser my question though. All the pngs I have in my app according to IB have an alpha channel. Does that mean they contain transparent pixels and should be marked 'Non Opaque'?